# R^2 into R^3 linear mapping - what exactly is the dimension of the map?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In a given example, my textbook says:

> For the spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ fix these bases.
>
> B = $\langle$ $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ $\rangle$         D = $\langle$ $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -2 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\1\end{pmatrix}$ $\rangle$
>
> Consider the map h : $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ that is determined by this association.
>
> $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ $\overset{h}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\1\end{pmatrix}$            $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ $\overset{h}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\0\end{pmatrix}$

Given this is the case, then what is the rank of h? It clearly has to be 2 since the dimension of the map is always less than or equal to the dimension of the domain, but in another theorem of the book, it states that (the important part isn't the theorem, but parts of the explanation the book uses to explain part of the theorem):

> THEOREM: The rank of a matrix equals the rank of any map that it represents.
>
> Suppose that the matrix H is m x n. Fix domain and codomain spaces V and W of dimension n and m with bases B = $\langle \vec{\beta_1}$, ..., $\vec{\beta_n} \rangle$ and D. Then H represents some linear map h between those spaces with respect to these bases whose range space
>                { h($\vec{v}$) | $\vec{v}$ E V} = { h($c_1 \vec{\beta_1} $ + ... + $c_n \vec{\beta_n}$ ) | $c_1$, ... , $c_n$ E $\mathbb{R}$ } 
>                                            = { $c_1$h($\vec{\beta_1}$) + ... + $c_n$h($\vec{\beta_n}$) | $c_1$, ... $c_n$ E $\mathbb{R}$ } 
> is the span [{h($\vec{\beta_1}$), ... h($\vec{\beta_1}$)}]. The rank of the map h is the dimension of this range space.              etc, etc...

The last statement seems to imply that the set {h($\vec{\beta_1}$), ... h($\vec{\beta_1}$)} is somehow a basis for the map h. But how can this be? Don't all bases in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have 3 elements? How can this one have 2, or am I missing something here?

Comment: The codomain is $\Bbb{R}^3$. The range is not $\Bbb{R}^3$, but a (proper) subspace. In fact, it's a two-dimensional subspace, spanned by $(1, 1, 1)^\top$ and $(1, 2, 0)^\top$. As these vectors are linearly independent, they form a basis for the range, proving the range is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do you know that the subspace is 2-dimensional? Intuitively, I understand that having only 2 members in its basis means that it can't be 3-dimensional, but I can't visualize it at all. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: The visual of a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ is a plane, passing through the origin. It's a subspace that looks a lot like $\Bbb{R}^2$, just floating in $\Bbb{R}^3$. For example, the $x$-$z$ plane is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$, and has a basis $\{(1, 0, 0)^\top, (0, 0, 1)^\top\}$. It has other bases too, but they all have $2$ vectors in them. This is how we know the dimension is $2$, without picturing it. As soon as we find a basis with $2$ vectors in it, then all bases will have $2$ vectors, and the dimension will be $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The rank of $h$ is the rank of the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\sim (R_1 \iff R_3)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\sim (-R_1+R_2\to R_2)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. There are $2$ pivots positions on row $1$ and $2$ each. Thus the rank is $2$.